# Facebook Video share using Azure media Service encoded streaming endpoints

Tags: azure, facebook-graph-api, video-streaming, azure-media-services

I am building a video library on Azure Media Service and want to give feature where my streaming endpoint(like manifest hls/Dashed/smooth streaming urls urls) can be shareable on Facebook like how YouTube URL works on Facebook share,

i am not sure, is this possible or not?? if yes than which encoding format i need to use here, i tried different encoding here but they didn't work for me,

if above cant be done than whats the best alternate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you need are:

1. Upload the source video (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-upload-files)
2. Encode it to a format that supports streaming, using Standard Encoder using a preset like "Content Adaptive Multiple Bitrate MP4" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-encode-with-media-encoder-standard)
3. Above will produce an output Asset containing multiple MP4 files
4. Publish this output Asset (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-deliver-streaming-content)
5. You can now use the streaming locator that step 4 generatesin Azure Media Player (http://aka.ms/amsplayer)

However, before you can share links on Facebook, you need to stand up another web service - I've let my colleague know about this thread, and she will follow up shortly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have already done above steps but while posting generated streaming locator, its posted as a urls, i am wondering how can i share urls like YouTube on fb so that it will run on fb page with play thumbnails  (similar to YouTube), I dont want to create a separate webpage/website  and share my website urls